# How can i format the string to add '-' between the numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
var startIndexTimeDate = file.Path.IndexOf("time=") + "time=".Length;
var lengthTimeDate = file.Path.IndexOf("&", startIndexTimeDate) - startIndexTimeDate;
var timeDate = file.Path.Substring(startIndexTimeDate, lengthTimeDate);
```

What i'm getting in timeDate for example is:

> 201702012015

And i want to format it to be:

> 01-02-20-15-2017

Not only for this number for every time i will do this code. The format should be this way since i want to create a directory of this format.

> 01-02-20-15-2017

Then i will want to read it back from the hard disk the directory name to a List but this time the string should be format as a date time for example:

> "01/02/2017 at 20:15"

So when i read it back i want to display it nicer to the user.

The directory on the hard disk will be in format of

> 01-02-20-15-2017

but when getting the directory name back to a List the format should be

> "01/02/2017 at 20:15"

Comment: Sounds like you should make `timeDate` a `DateTime` object instead of a string object. That way you can have all the formats you want depending on what you pass in to `timeDate.ToString("...")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to parse DateTime object from your string, and after that format it in any way you want:

```
var s = "201702012015";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyyMMddHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var dirName = date.ToString("dd-MM-HH-mm-yyyy"); //01-02-20-15-2017
```

Then do the same when reading directory

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dirName, "dd-MM-HH-mm-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var nameInList = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy a\\t HH:mm"); //01/02/2017 at 20:15
```